How to ignore cases when using 'Except' in snowflake?
Is there a way we can ignore lower and upper cases when using the 'except' keyword?
Lets say I have a table 'table1' with column 'col1' with value 'hello'.
I have another table 'table2' with column 'col1' with value 'HELLO'.
If I write the below query as,
select col1 from table1 
except
select col1 from table2;

I get the result as 'hello'.
Is there a way we can ignore these lower and upper cases and just get empty results when we run this query. I have a requirement to use 'except' clause itself here.

You can use COLLATE to solve for this:
SELECT COLLATE(col1, 'en-ci') as col1 FROM table1
EXCEPT
SELECT COLLATE(col1, 'en-ci') as col1 FROM table2;

You can also set collation of these columns when you create the table to be case-insensitive if that is the intention of this data.
There's other options at this snowflake article as well.

To ignore cases when using the 'EXCEPT' set operation in Snowflake, you can use the 'ILIKE' operator or the 'LOWER()' function. Here are two approaches:
Using ILIKE:
sqlCopySELECT column1, column2
FROM table1
EXCEPT
SELECT column1, column2
FROM table2
WHERE table1.column1 NOT ILIKE table2.column1
Using LOWER():
sqlCopySELECT LOWER(column1), column2
FROM table1
EXCEPT
SELECT LOWER(column1), column2
FROM table2
The ILIKE operator performs a case-insensitive comparison, while the LOWER() function converts all characters to lowercase before comparison.
Choose the method that best fits your specific use case. The ILIKE approach may be more flexible if you need to compare only certain columns case-insensitively, while the LOWER() method ensures all string comparisons are case-insensitive.
